# Pandas Merge Function, Saving Leftover values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using merge function on a column for two dataframes... how can I save the leftover values from dataframe 1 ( df_csv_deduped) and store it in some rows on the bottom of the frame

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_csv_deduped, df_excel_deduped_values, how='inner', on=['Incident ID'])
```

Comment: why don't you use `how='left'` and possibly `indicator=True`

Comment: @QuangHoang the second dataset is quite large and if they don't match up with any incident Id's i don't really care about them and dont want to see them in my merge file at all, however I do care about the first datasets leftovers that didnt find a match

Comment: Yes, then try my comment. Also, you can try `isin`. There are some questions on SO about this already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use how='outer' to merge everything and filter then first on both, append to a new DF. Afterwards filter on left and append as well